# Reusing RSpec tests in other tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm very rigorous when it comes to my HTML markup and I follow a strict coding convention for forms, lists, etc...

I would like to include reusable test in my RSpec tests that would allow for me call a form test from any other test and target it directly to the page or URL that I'm testing.

Something like this:

```
# spec/helpers/form_tester.rb
describe FormTester
  it "should check to see if all the text fields have an ID prefix of 'input-'" do
    ... @form should be valid ...
    should be true
  end
end

# spec/requests/user_form.rb
describe UserForm
  it "should validate the form" do
    @form = find(:tag,'form')
    # call the FormTester method        
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how todo this? I'm using Rails 3.1, with RSpec, Capybara and FactoryGirl.

Comment: you should create a method containing your test code and call it from both places

Answer (score 11):

Use [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples). In you case, something like this may work:

```
# spec/shared_examples_for_form.rb
shared_examples 'a form' do
  describe 'validation' do
    it 'should be validated' do
      form.should_be valid
    end
  end
end

# spec/requests/user_form.rb
describe UserForm
  it_behaves_like 'a form' do
    let(:form) { find(:tag, 'form') }
  end
end
```

It's also possible to pass parameters to shared examples and place the shared examples inside `spec/support`. Just have a read at the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

Comment: Just a note: I had to move the shared_example spec-file into the spec/support directory (and then I restarted guard) in order to get the above advice to work.

Answer (score 1):

Shared examples are great, but you've got at least two serious problems here.

First: why are you giving your form fields IDs at all? You've already got perfectly good selectors: just use `input[name='whatever']`. And even if you *are* giving them IDs, don't put a prefix on them: `input#whatever` or just `#whatever` is probably a more sensible selector in your CSS than `#input-whatever`. By being overspecific on your selector names, you're most likely making your CSS and JavaScript harder to write than they have to be.

Second: don't use RSpec to test your views. RSpec is at its best when confined to models. Cucumber is better for anything user-facing.

Comment: not necessary Cucumber, RSpec with support of capybara/webrat can be good as well for view or integration tests

Comment: @Artur79 No, it can't. Cucumber is necessary, because you need to be doing your view and integration tests from the point of view of the UI -- and defining them in terms of UI actions. RSpec *looks* like it works for integration tests, but in fact it introduces a subtle but very real theoretical wrongness by defining your tests in programmer terms. This couples your tests too closely to implementation, and so you're not testing what you think you are.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: "you need to be doing your view and integration tests from the point of view of the UI -- and defining them in terms of UI actions". That's exactly what Capybara does. Cucumber is not necessary for anything. I personally don't find it as useful as rspec/capybara combo.

Comment: @Zyren Cucumber is necessary to prevent you from thinking like a programmer when you're writing UI tests. If you find Cucumber a hindrance, you're probably thinking at a lower level of abstraction than you should be when writing UI tests.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-KoserYou Capybara does exactly that. All my tests with capybara are UI actions such as visiting a URL, clicking on buttons, filling out html inputs, etc, and i can see them being done through firefox when i run my tests. Cucumber may work for you, but rspec/capybara also works and is just as capable for view/UI tests. There are many large rails projects, such as Spree, that use capybara instead of cucumber.

Comment: @Zyren Right, they're UI actions such as clicking buttons. They're not declarative statements of the *intent* behind the UI (see http://web.archive.org/web/20130424133851/http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off and http://www.elabs.se/blog/15-you-re-cuking-it-wrong). The level of abstraction is too low, which is what I meant by "thinking like a programmer". RSpec without Cucumber is not "just as capable", unless you abstract the UI actions into declarative functions—and then you might as well use Cucumber.

Comment: @Zyren Also, for speed and reliability, you should normally run Capybara headless (with capybara-webkit or similar if JavaScript is required). With something like capybara-firebug, you can always temporarily watch one scenario run if you really need to. And based on my experience with Spree, I'm not sure it's a particularly shining example of Railscraft. :) It's far from the worst Rails project I've seen, but it isn't the best, either.

Comment: @Zyren FWIW, I just took a look at Spree's features. They're about the best job I've seen of doing this without Cucumber, but I think they're still too low-level much of the time—the temptation is just too hard to resist—and they don't convey user intent nearly as well as Cucumber stories would. (By the time you've written a few methods like Spree's `add_mug_to_cart`, I think you've reinvented an inferior version of Cucumber anyway…so why not use the real thing?)